# how to write the regular expression to allow dashes in the date

Tags: javascript, regex

I write a regular expression as below

```
var validformat = /\d\d?[\-\/]\d\d?[\-\/](19\d\d|200\d)$/
```

it wont take dates like : 08-12-2008 but 08/12/2008 works. What's the problem?

Comment: What is the string you're trying to match your regex against?

Comment: Paste us code proving an actual string date like "08-12-2008" did not match... you presumably had trailing whitespace at the end which broke the $ field. Remove the $ and verify it matched. Proves it's the $.

Answer (score 0):

You presumably had trailing whitespace at the end which broke the $ field.
Otherwise the regex as written is fine.

Paste us code proving an actual string date like "08-12-2008" did not match...

Remove the $ and verify it matched. Proves it's the $.

Answer (score -1):

Slash should not be escaped. Try this:

```
var validformat = /\d\d?[\-/]\d\d?[\-/](19\d\d|200\d)$/
```

Comment: In JavaScript regex literals, they must be escaped. In string literals, not necessarily.